# Division in group by SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, precision

I have the following SQL code

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) filter (WHERE has_a)) AS count_a, 
COUNT(*) AS total_count,
process_date
FROM(SELECT process_date::date AS process_date,
    (CASE WHEN (columnA > 0) THEN true ELSE false END) AS has_a
    FROM my_table)
temptable
GROUP BY process_date
LIMIT 5;
```

which gives the following table

[image]

I want to create a column called percent_a with value `(count_a/total_count)*100` grouped by `process_date`. E.g for row 1 the new column would have value 49.4 i.e. (1030/2085)*100.

I have tried

```
SELECT process_date,
    ((COUNT(*) filter (WHERE has_a))/COUNT(*) * 100) AS percent_a,
    FROM(SELECT process_date::date AS process_date,
        (CASE WHEN (columnA > 0) THEN true ELSE false END) AS has_a,
         FROM my_table)
temptable
GROUP BY process_date
ORDER BY process_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But this just gave 0s.

[image]

How can I create the column to display the % I want? I think something is happening with the `GROUP BY` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hint: `select 1/2 x, 1.0/2 y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `count` returns an integer, you just need to cast it:

```
SELECT process_date,
    (((COUNT(*) filter (WHERE has_balance))::DOUBLE PRECISION)/COUNT(*) * 100) AS percent_a,
    FROM(SELECT process_date::date AS process_date,
        (CASE WHEN (columnA > 0) THEN true ELSE false END) AS has_a,
         FROM my_table)
temptable
GROUP BY process_date
ORDER BY process_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```